A movie where the villain is a sniper
There are only two scenes which I can still vividly remember. 
The movie was maybe from the late 90s to the early 2000s and in color. It is in english language, and the story may be from US or Britain. The movie is about a serial sniper killings which the police and other law enforcement agencies are investigating. 

On one scene, the sniper shoots from inside a van parked outside a public street from a cutout he had made. He is shooting someone on a wheelchair at the opposite building through the glass window I think (maybe a witness with some guards and lawyers) that were running inside the building but he still hits the guy)
On the second scene, it was in a forested area where there is a stage I think to which a political speech, a rally, or a concert may have been held. 

Police and a detective are searching for clues and one detective is looking at a tree which he believes the sniper may have taken that shot. 
These are the only 2 scenes I have and you can imagine my struggle to search the title of this movie. 

Any chance this was a TV episode?
